# Java class change to Servlet | What is going wrong - twitter4j

Tags: java, servlets

i have the java code below. I run it on eclipse such as a classic java project and all is fine

```
import java.util.List;
import twitter4j.Query;
import twitter4j.QueryResult;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;

public class TwitterTest {

    public static String API_Key = new String("**************");
    public static String API_Secret = new String("*************");
    public static String Access_Token = new String("**************");
    public static String Access_Token_Secret = new String("*********");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(API_Key, API_Secret);
        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(Access_Token, Access_Token_Secret);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);        

        Query q = new Query("goal");
        q.setCount(10);

        QueryResult res = null;
        try {
            res = twitter.search(q);
            List<Status> list = res.getTweets();
            //for (Status s : list) {
            //System.out.println(s.getText());
            //}
            for (int i=0 ; i < list.size() ; i++) {
                Status s = list.get(i);             
                //System.out.println(s);
                System.out.println(s.getText());
            }
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



}
```

Now i want see results on browser. So i try to convert this java class to a servlet.

i have setup tomcat7, i have run classic helloworld servlet. Now i try to create this convertion but all is go wrong.

```
import java.io.*; 
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;

import java.util.List;

/** Very simplistic servlet that generates plain text.
 *  <P>
 *  Taken from Core Servlets and JavaServer Pages 2nd Edition
 *  from Prentice Hall and Sun Microsystems Press,
 *  http://www.coreservlets.com/.
 *  &copy; 2003 Marty Hall; may be freely used or adapted.
 */

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello World - YEs, yes, yes!!! Nooooooo!sdfkalfk");

        String API_Key = new String("*************");
        String API_Secret = new String("********************");
        String Access_Token =   new String("************");
        String Access_Token_Secret = new String("**********");

        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(API_Key, API_Secret);
        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(Access_Token, Access_Token_Secret);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

        Query q = new Query("goal");
        q.setCount(10);

        QueryResult res = null;
        try {
            res = twitter.search(q);
            List<Status> list = res.getTweets();
            //for (Status s : list) {
            //System.out.println(s.getText());
            //}
            for (int i=0 ; i < list.size() ; i++) {
                Status s = list.get(i);             
                //System.out.println(s);
                out.println(s.getText());
            }
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
}
```

You can post me the basic faults and put in right guides?

Thnx,
Ilias

EDIT:

I can't compile. I get this:

```
itsoum@itsoum-Inspiron-3542:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes$ sudo javac -classpath /home/itsoum/Downloads/twitter4j-4.0.1/*.jar HelloWorld.java
HelloWorld.java:2: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.*;
^
HelloWorld.java:3: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.*;
^
HelloWorld.java:6: error: package twitter4j does not exist
import twitter4j.*;
^
HelloWorld.java:7: error: package twitter4j.auth does not exist
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
                     ^
HelloWorld.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
                                ^
  symbol: class HttpServlet
HelloWorld.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    ^
  symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
                    HttpServletResponse response)
                    ^
  symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
      throws ServletException, IOException {
             ^
  symbol:   class ServletException
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        ^
  symbol:   class Twitter
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                              ^
  symbol:   class TwitterFactory
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(Access_Token, Access_Token_Secret);
        ^
  symbol:   class AccessToken
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(Access_Token, Access_Token_Secret);
                                      ^
  symbol:   class AccessToken
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
        Query q = new Query("goal");
        ^
  symbol:   class Query
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
        Query q = new Query("goal");
                      ^
  symbol:   class Query
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
        QueryResult res = null;
        ^
  symbol:   class QueryResult
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
            List<Status> list = res.getTweets();
                 ^
  symbol:   class Status
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
                Status s = list.get(i);             
                ^
  symbol:   class Status
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                     ^
  symbol:   class TwitterException
  location: class HelloWorld
18 errors
```

Comment: Move it `out.println(s.getText());` outside for loop

Comment: what error you are getting? is it saying something like illegalstate?

Comment: try flushing / closing output stream, i.e, out.flush(); out.close();

Comment: @Arpit if move it out from for loop i take only the first json answer.

Comment: If you want all, collect in some data structure and write it on output stream.

Comment: @vembutech basic i can't compile it.  i run on terminal -> sudo javac -classpath /usr/share/tomcat7/lib/*.jar HelloWorld.java  and i take this  ->  javac: invalid flag: /usr/share/tomcat7/lib/catalina-ant.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
Obvious i have put in this dictionary twitter4j api jars

Comment: have you added your twitter.jar libs in the lib folder? and set classpath to them?

Comment: @vembutech yeap i have already do this. I put only required jars on a folder and i get this(look the last entry on my first post) now.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you wouldn't compile a servlet from the command line like this.  The servlet container (tomcat) would compile it for you.

However if you are in the debug phase I note  you haven't included the javax.servlet classes in the build path.  If you are using eclipse, create a dynamic web project.  Create the servlet (new servlet) in a package under the source directory.  Now make sure that the runtime environment is pointing at a tomcat server.  This will include the correct servlet jar files.

For the twitter4j jar files you'll need to add them to the project build.  In the java build path add them as external jar directories.   Finally to run the project, make sure the jar files are in the lib directory of the base tomcat installation.  This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Av6zh817QEc  might help